# Is there a Naruto manga that goes over kid Kakashi?

Tags: naruto

I know some of kid Kakashi's story from *Naruto: Ultimate Ninja Storm* games but I would really like to read more about it.

Is there a *Naruto* manga that goes over kid Kakashi?

Answer (score 3):

Let me help you.

You can read Kakashi Gaiden which covers his backstory when he was a kid. You can watch 119 to 120 of Naruto Shippuden also. I would suggest if you have and interest in Naruto the series and want to see where the characters started and orignated, watch Naruto and then Shippuden.

Comment: Naruto Volume 27 as well. It goes over Kid Kakashi in the third Shinobi war.